# Named parameters confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the following code: (WebMethod attribute in web service)

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 300)]
public string GetData(string Id)
{

}
```

The intellisense for the WebMethod attribute class constructor shows the second overload as named parameters.
My doubt is that aren't named parameter values specified using a colon (:) after the parameter name. How come an equal to operator is used here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a third syntax particular to attributes, in which you can specify fields to initialize on the attribute instance using a Name = Value syntax in the constructor call.

```
[WebMethod(cacheDuration: 300)]
```

would work just as well, but it's using standard named-parameter syntax instead of attribute field-initialization syntax. Remember that attributes were around before named parameters existed.

Comment: I tried using CacheDuration:300 , it shows that message "best overload does not have parameter named CacheDuration"

Comment: @Amit: That's because I got the name of the parameter wrong (it should have been lowercase) ;-)

Comment: Yeah you are right...so to sum it up, the syntax with equal to is actually initializing fields via properties ?

Comment: @Amit: It's initializing public fields *or* properties with the corresponding name

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with WebMethod's properties.

Look at this VALID code:

```
class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    [Test(MyProperty=300)]
    public void method1()
    {
    }
}
```

If you look at the Metadata for WebMethod, there is a property called "CacheDuration".