# Why Does Named Parameter For A Custom Attribute Require `:` Syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, intellisense

I defined the following custom attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private MyPermissionLevels requestedAccessLevel;

    public CustomAuthAttribute(object AccessLevel = null)
    {
        AccessLevel = AccessLevel ?? MyPermissionLevels.View;            
        if(AccessLevel.GetType() != typeof(MyPermissionLevels))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("AccessLevel is invalid.");
        }
        this.requestedAccessLevel = (MyPermissionLevels)AccessLevel;
    }

        ... // Other Auth Stuff
}
```

When I apply this attribute to a controller as, for example, `[CustomAuthAttribute (AccessLevel = MyPermissionLevels.Modify)]` intellisense complains that:

> The type or namespace name 'AccessLevel' could not be found. (*etc?*)

The potential fixes revealed by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> include:

> Change 'AccessLevel' to 'AccessLevel:'

Adding this colon (and by implication removing the `=` operator, which is not an automagical part of the suggested fix) does resolve the compilation error.

I am okay using a different syntax if that's all that need be. However, **I would like to understand what I've done that prevents me from using the more common attribute field-initialization syntax** as described in answers to [Named parameters confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920994/named-parameters-confusion) and as can be done with the parent class:

`[Authorize(Roles = "Modifiers")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon is necessary because that is the syntax for named parameters. The field isn't public, nor are you trying to assign to it.  The field's name is `requestedAccessLevel`, not `AccessLevel`.

The parent class has a public property `Roles`, so in the line:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Modifiers")]
```

`Roles` is not a named constructor parameter, it's a property, so named parameter syntax is not used.  Indeed, that attribute doesn't have a constructor that accepts parameters.  It only has public, assignable properties.

Answer (score 1):

`[CustomAuthAttribute (MyPermissionLevels.Modify)]` should be ok.

The form `[CustomAuthAttribute (AccessLevel = MyPermissionLevels.Modify)]` means that you use a parameterless constructor and in parallel assign a value to a property named `AccessLevel`.

Instead, you should provide a value for the parameter. 
You do this either by simply providing the value or by using the named parameter form `(parameter_name + ':')`.